# Dojo Date text box invalid message hide

Tags: dojo, datepicker

I want to disable or not show the invalid tooltip message.
Im creating date textbox like this

```html
this.createDateTextBox = function() {
  this.dateTextbox = new dijit.form.DateTextBox({
   name : this.name,
   id : this.name
  });
 };
```

```html
this.setProperties = function(){
  this.dateTextbox.constraints={selector:'date',required: false, datePattern:'dd MMMM yyyy', min:new Date()} 
 };
```

I dont want to show invalid tooltip message as shown in attached image[image]

Comment: I have tried the below 3 types of code : dijit.byId("newHolidayDate").attr('_InvalidMessage', 'John is not allowed');                      holidayDateSelectBox.attr('promptMessage','Please Enter a date in MM/dd/yyyy format');                        holidayDateSelectBox.set("message",'John is not allowed');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the tooltip message by overriding it's displayMessage function with an empty function.

Example:

```
this.dateTextbox = new dijit.form.DateTextBox({
            name : this.name,
            id : this.name,
            displayMessage : function(){

            }
        });
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kagant15/4vud29jt/